# reverse google image search via URL after 2022 switch to Google Lens

Tags: google-image-search

Until recently, it was possible to do a reverse google image search via URL parameter: `https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=https://foo/bar.jpg`. However, Google has started to redirect everything to Google Lens, so I'm now ending up at https://www.google.com/imghp?sbi=1 (this may not be the case for you yet, but sooner or later it probably will). I could manually paste the picture URL there and click on "Find image source" go get the same search results as before, but I'm looking for a URL parameter. Has anybody figured this out yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It still works when you add a `client` query parameter to the url with any value:
`https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=<your_url>&client=app`

Example: https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.png&client=app

Comment: I am confused, how are you making this work? How do I supply 1.Image (as URL or otherwise local upload),  2. Site restrictions for said image? Please elaborate.

Comment: @AlexS 1. You replace the token `<your_url>` with an existing URL that points to an image.  2. What does "site restrictions for said image" mean?